# The font used by Microsoft Word 2007 equations

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

I want to write some mathematical expressions in a web page and I really like the font used in Word 2007 equations; I want to use it but I don't know its name; can anybody help me, please?

Comment: Consider that some users won't have that font installed and default font will be used. Maybe embedding a web font would be a better choice.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/428928/microsoft-word-how-to-use-equation-font-elsewhere?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font used in the Equation editor of Microsoft Word 2010 is called:

> *Cambria Math*

It is available on a typical Windows 7/8 installation and I presume XP.

Hope I helped. :D

Note: The font is also italicized in some cases.

Comment: In that case, if you could upvote and accept my answer, respectively clicking the grey up arrow and the green tick, to facilitate other users from benefiting from this. :D

Comment: Cambria Math is available (in somewhat different versions as regards to character coverage) on Windows Vista and newer, but not XP, see http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=2113

Comment: Cambria Math has no italic typeface. When using Equation Tools, Word automatically changes e.g. the letter “x” to a different character, U+1D465, MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL X, which is inherently italic. This is one of the reasons that make Cambria Math very problematic on web pages.